# difference between "break free of" and "break free from"

Tags: differences, phrase-usage

What is the difference between "break free of" and "break free from"?

I looked up to the dictionaries, I got the meaning of both while I still don't know how tho use them?

definition:
1\break free of something or someone
IDIOM:
=  escape (from), leave, withdraw from, extricate yourself from, free yourself of, disentangle yourself from •  his inability to break free of his marriage

2\break something free (from something)
to force something to detach from something; to get something out of the hold of something else. I broke the gun free from her grasp. Someone broke the light fixture free from its mounting. free (from something)
to force something to detach from something; to get something out of the hold of something else. I broke the gun free from her grasp. Someone broke the light fixture free from its mounting.

3\break free from sb/ sth   no rusult

Answer (score 3):

They mean essentially the same.  "Of" is more likely to be used when "break free" is used figuratively to imply freeing something from the influences of something else, while "from" is more likely to be used when physically separating something from something else.  But that's not a hard-and-fast rule.